# Saving JSON data to server using AngularJS - disappears on page refresh

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http, refresh

I'm writing a single-page web app using AngularJS. It includes a table containing data pulled from a JSON file sitting on a server. I am using the `$http` service to make a `$http.get()` call to fill the table from this file.

Also on the page is a form used to add data to the table. I am using `$http.post()` to add data from the form to the JSON file (which seemingly works fine because my `.success()` callback runs after the post call is made).

However, whenever I refresh the page, I find that the data I supposedly posted is not represented in the table. Is a `$http` request not enough to save data to a file permanently?

**UPDATE:**

My `$http.post()` does NOT work correctly. My JSON file never gets updated after the post request. Not sure why. See below code:

```
$scope.postNewJob = function(newJob) {
    $http.post('json/jobList.json', newJob)
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);

        })
        .error(function(data,status,error,config) {
            alert("Error: "+error+" Post to server failed.\nStatus: "+status);
        });
};
```

Comment: Are you writing the file to the server?

Comment: This is not the question someone can help you with. No one knows what you do on the server with posted data. So the only possible recommendation: check server side scripts, DB, etc, response status in console.

Comment: Success means a nice http status. It says nothing about a successful data save.

Comment: I double checked my code, and my $http.post never actually updated my json file at all. I edited my question to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

I am asuming you are saving the data correctly to the server and the issue is the GET request for the JSON data is being cached. To get around it you can use a querystring parameter to bust the cache or set the proper no cache headers on the server.

```
$http({
    url: '...',
    params: { 'ts': new Date().getTime() }
})
```